# Can't transform list of arrays into 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have 3 classifiers that run over 288 samples. All of them are `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` structures. Here is the code i am using:

```py
list_of_clfs = [MLPClassifier(...),  MLPClassifier(...), MLPClassifier(...)] 

probas_list = []

for clf in list_of_clfs:
   probas_list.append(clf.predict_proba(X_test))
```

Each `predict_proba(X_test)` will return a 2D array with shape (n_samples, n_classes). Then, i am creating a 3D array that will contain all `predict_proba()` in one single place:

```py
   proba = np.array(probas_list) #this should return a (3, n_samples, n_classes) array
```

This should work fine, but i get an error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (288,4) into shape (288)
```

I don't know why, but this works with dummy examples but not with my dataset.

**update**: it seems like one of the `predict_proba()` calls is returning an array of shape `(288, 2)` but my problem has 4 classes. All classifiers are being tested on the same dataset, so i don't know what this comes from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Often when making an array from arrays that differ in shape, the result is a 1d array with object dtype (and ragged array warning), but with your combination of shapes (288,4) and (288,2) the result is your error.

Comment: Yes, i found out why. Before training, data is distributed among classifiers. So one of the classifiers is receiving just one class. I am already working on a fix for this, do you know how to interpret `predict_proba()` when classifier was trained on just one class?